# Graphs: jQuery - What kind of graph is this? State/status-vs-time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, graph

I'm looking for a way to graph this kind of chart.  I was trying to do it manually with HTML tables and PHP loops, but the up-and-down nature of the plots makes it seemingly impossible that way.  I've tried searching Google for Javascript charting, but not knowing the name I haven't had any success.

X-axis is time (hours in a day, broken down as small as possible) and Y-axis is the state.  I have 4 in this example, but I could have a variable number in the system.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HighCharts](http://jsfiddle.net/xfLmjyek/)

You can add your time categories to xAxis, or you can set the type to `datetime` : http://jsfiddle.net/4w32jgps/1/